# How to setup cross domain tracking on google analytics using content experiments

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

Please help. I've been working on this all day. Here's the deal...

I have got 2 domains.

domain1.com and domain2.com

I want to setup cross domain tracking on google analytics for these domains.

I also have an A/B content experiment setup on domain2.com

I've read these 2 pages.

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2658141
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#yourDomainName

From what I understand I need to put the following into the google analytics code for domain1.com

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain1.com']);
```

And this needs to go into the google analytics code for domain2.com

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain2.com']);
```

I also need to put this in front of my control script for my experiment...

```
<script>
_udn = "domain2.com";
</script>
```

I also have to use this code when linking from domain1.com to domain2.com

```
<a href="domain2.com/experiment/location" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'domain2.com/experiment/location']); return false;">Link to domain2</a>
```

Here's the problem... 
In 1 scenario the cookie isn't being passed between the 2 domains.
In another scenario it **is** passed between the 2 domains

Scenario 1 (Doesn't work)

1. Navigate to domain1.com
2. Click link to domain2.com/experiment/location (this is where the control script is located)

Scenario 2 (Does work)

1. Navigate to domain1.com
2. Click link to domain2.com/some/other/page
3. Click link to domain2.com/experiment/location (this is where the control script is located)

Somehow visiting another page on domain2.com before visiting the experiment allows the cookie information to be passed.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you using `_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true])`?

Comment: Yes I am. I've done some experimenting with adding the google analytics code above the content experiments code and it keeps the cookie intact. But it also registers a double pageview.